# Unpack right side of assignment in python

Tags: python

Often, I need to a few empty lists (when doing some experiments in ipython that are meant to by tried and forgotten). Is there something elegant way to do:

```
list1,list2,list3,list4 = [],[],[],[]
```

I have in mind something like

```
l1,l2,l3,l4 = *[]
```

which does not work of course.

Comment: @Brobin, No. All 4 then refer to the SAME object.

Comment: Why don't you just make a list of lists, rather than separate names? `lists = [[] for _ in range(4)]`?

Comment: `l1, l2, l3, l4 = [[]]*4`  EDIT: @Andy is still right...

Comment: The answer referred to is clever, but as Alex points out you need to count your left side items for your Range on the right.  What happens if you hook up an iterator-based objecton the right?  Would it not automatically unpack as many empty lists as desired?

Comment: @JLPeyret I would think that this wouldn't be possible, as it would not be possible for the number of variables left of an assignment operator in source to ever change. It would always be known how many there are. This functionality would exclusively be useful for interactive testing.

Comment: @jonrshape: well, because `peaches` and `oranges` is easier for my head to handle than l[0], l[1]. It is just for throwaway coding when I explore my data.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the duplicate!

Comment: @Aaron.  Well, it might be useful in cases where you want to initialize a bunch of stuff on the left, but not maintain the count on the right.  Kind of an edge case, but I tried it to see how iterators would work.  They don't help, it seems the assignment "empties" the full iterator at one go, rather than asking a next() one by one (i.e. for each left target).  That's on Python 2.7.  It's not totally frivolous either, mistakenly sharing mutable references (through a = b = [] or the infamous default function variables) is one of my prime areas of bugs on Python.